# Converting event based API to Rx.Net

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to convert an existing event-based API to a Reactive Observable API. The concrete API I'm working with is the `NSNetServiceBrowser` in Xamarin.iOS. This API let you browse for network devices using Zeroconf/Bonjour. However, the question would apply to any API of this kind.

The `NsNetServiceBrowser` offers various events of interest: 
 - `FoundService`
 - `NotSearched`
 - `ServiceRemoved`

The `FoundService` event is raised when a service is discovered, and the `NotSearched` is raised when the search fails.

I would like to combine the `FoundService` and `NotSerched` events, into an observable of `NSNetService`.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
public IObservable<NSNetService> Search()
{
    var foundObservable = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<NSNetServiceEventArgs>(
            h => serviceBrowser.FoundService += h,
            h => serviceBrowser.FoundService -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    var notSearchedObservable = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<NSNetServiceErrorEventArgs>(
            h => serviceBrowser.NotSearched += h,
            h => serviceBrowser.NotSearched -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    var serviceObservable = Observable.Create(
        (IObserver<NSNetServiceEventArgs> observer) =>
        {
            notSearchedObservable.Subscribe(n =>
            {
                string errorMessage = $"Search for {serviceType} failed:";
                foreach (var kv in n.Errors)
                {
                    log.Error($"\t{kv.Key}: {kv.Value}");
                    errorMessage += $" ({kv.Key}, {kv.Value})";
                }
                observer.OnError(new Exception(errorMessage));
            });
            foundObservable.Subscribe(observer);
            return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
    }).Select(x => x.Service);

    serviceBrowser.SearchForServices(serviceType, domain);
    return serviceObservable;
}
```

The code looks clunky and I have a gut feeling I'm not using `System.Reactive` correctly? Is there a more elegant way to combine event pairs, where one is producing and the other is signaling error? This is a common pattern in existing event based APIs in .NET.

---

Here is a small console app (depending only on System.Reactive) illustrating the type of API I want to Reactify:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReactiveLearning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var browser = new ServiceBrowser();

            var observableFound =
                Observable.FromEventPattern<ServiceFoundEventArgs>(
                    h => browser.ServiceFound += h,
                    h => browser.ServiceFound -= h)
                .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Service);

            var observableError =
                Observable.FromEventPattern<ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs>(
                    h => browser.ServiceError += h,
                    h => browser.ServiceError -= h);

            var foundSub = observableFound.Subscribe(s =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found service: {s.Name}");
            }, () => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Completed");
            });

            var errorSub = observableError.Subscribe(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
            }, () => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Completed");
            });

            browser.Search();

            Console.ReadLine();

            foundSub.Dispose();
            errorSub.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    class ServiceBrowser
    {
        public EventHandler<ServiceFoundEventArgs> ServiceFound;
        public EventHandler<ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs> ServiceError;

        public void Search()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    ServiceFound?.Invoke(this, new ServiceFoundEventArgs(new Service($"Service {i}")));
                }

                var r = new Random();
                if (r.NextDouble() > 0.5)
                {
                    ServiceError?.Invoke(this, new ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class ServiceFoundEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Service Service { get; private set;  }
        public ServiceFoundEventArgs(Service service) => Service = service;
    }

    class ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs : EventArgs {}

    class Service
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AddressResolved;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ErrorResolvingAddress;
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Address { get; private set; }
        public Service(string name) => Name = name;

        public void ResolveAddress()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                var r = new Random();
                if (r.NextDouble() > 0.5)
                {                    
                    Address = $"http://{Name}.com";
                    AddressResolved?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorResolvingAddress?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, whenever you do `return Disposable.Empty;` you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It's going to be as simple as something like `return foundObservable.Select(x => x.Service).Merge(notSearchedObservable.Select(x => x.Service));`, but you haven't posted your class definitions so I can't say for sure. Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't want to merge them - I want one Observable, where an element produced by notSearchedObservable will raise an error (not produce an element). I'll see if I can create a general small example of what I want to "reactify"

Comment: Here is a small console app (depending only on System.Reactive) illustrating the type of API I want to Reactify: https://gist.github.com/follesoe/60669ea2c5112cd733181d7870ba93da

Comment: If an error is raised should that immediately stop your observable or should it continue and be able to report multiple errors?

Comment: In other words are you want to call `OnError` which ends the observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the excellent sample code. You need to make use of the excellent `Materialize` & `Dematerialize` operators. Here's how:

```
var observableFoundWithError =
    observableFound
        .Materialize()
        .Merge(
            observableError
                .Materialize()
                .Select(x =>
                    Notification
                        .CreateOnError<Service>(new Exception("Error"))))
        .Dematerialize()
        .Synchronize();

using (observableFoundWithError.Subscribe(
    s => Console.WriteLine($"Found service: {s.Name}"),
    ex => Console.WriteLine($"Found error: {ex.Message}"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("Found Completed")))
{
    browser.Search();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `Materialize()` operator turns an `IObservable<T>` into and `IObservable<Notification<T>>` which allows the standard `OnError` and `OnCompleted` to be emitted through the `OnNext` call. You can use `Notification.CreateOnError<T>(new Exception("Error"))` to construct elements of observable which you can turn back into an `IObservable<T>` with `Dematerialize()`.

I've thrown the `Synchronize()` to ensure that you've created a valid observable. The use of `Materialize()` does let you construct observables that don't follow the regular observable contract. Part of what `Synchronize()` does is just ensure only one `OnError` and only one `OnCompleted` and drops any `OnNext` that comes after either of the two.

---

Try this as a way to do what you wanted in the comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var browser = new ServiceBrowser();

    var observableFound =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<ServiceFoundEventArgs>(
            h => browser.ServiceFound += h,
            h => browser.ServiceFound -= h)
        .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Service);

    var observableError =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs>(
            h => browser.ServiceError += h,
            h => browser.ServiceError -= h);

    var observableFoundWithError = observableFound
        .Materialize()
        .Merge(
            observableError
                .Materialize()
                .Select(x => Notification.CreateOnError<Service>(new Exception("Error"))))
        .Dematerialize()
        .Synchronize();

    Func<Service, IObservable<Service>> resolveService = s =>
        Observable.Create<Service>(o =>
        {
            var observableResolved = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(
                h => s.AddressResolved += h,
                h => s.AddressResolved -= h);

            var observableResolveError = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(
                h => s.ErrorResolvingAddress += h,
                h => s.ErrorResolvingAddress -= h);

            var observableResolvedWithError =
                observableResolved
                    .Select(x => s)
                    .Materialize()
                    .Merge(
                        observableResolveError
                        .Do(e => Console.WriteLine($"Error resolving: {s.Name}"))
                        .Materialize()
                        .Select(x => Notification.CreateOnError<Service>(new Exception($"Error resolving address for service: {s.Name}"))))
                    .Dematerialize()
                    .Synchronize();

            s.ResolveAddress();

            return observableResolvedWithError.Subscribe(o);
        });

    using (
        observableFoundWithError
            .Select(s => resolveService(s))
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(
                s => Console.WriteLine($"Found and resolved service: {s.Name} ({s.Address})"),
                ex => Console.WriteLine($"Found error: {ex.Message}"),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Found Completed")))
    {
        browser.Search();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ServiceBrowser
{
    public event EventHandler<ServiceFoundEventArgs> ServiceFound;
    public event EventHandler<ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs> ServiceError;

    public void Search() { }
}

public class Service
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AddressResolved;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ErrorResolvingAddress;

    public string Name;
    public string Address;

    public void ResolveAddress() { }
}

public class ServiceFoundEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Service Service;
}

public class ServiceSearchErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{

}
```

I might require a bit of tweaking - perhaps an `Observable.Delay` in there. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Awesome! And this answers my original questions - so I will mark it as accepted. However, I did forget to mention that I would also like the `Service` only to be produced in the observable stream after it's resolved. So once a service is found; I would need to call `ResolveAddress` and return the service on `AddressResolved` or throw error on `ErrorResolvingAddress`. So I guess I would have to make some kind of internal stream (using Materialize/DeMaterialize) as the services are found?

Comment: You'd have to show me the normal execution of the code for me to answer.

Comment: Here is an updated gist trying to extend on your solution. As far as I understand I'm now dealing with a side-effect in the Rx world. As services are discovered, I need to call the `ResolveAddress` method. I then want to "delay" producing services until their addresses can be resolved. In my example, I try to do this by using `Subject<T>`, and then subscribing to the Observable you created, calling `ResolveAddress`, and then issuing `OnNext` or `OnError` on the `Subject<Service>`.

https://gist.github.com/follesoe/70ed091e3d5f13c7b4138e071687088d

Comment: I'm away from my computer this morning so if I forget to forget to respond please ping me in about 12 hours. Just briefly there should never be a need to create queries within a subscribe. It's fixable.

Comment: @JonasFollesø - I managed to sneak in some time on my tablet. I've got an updated answer for you. It compiles (I had to write test classes for that), but I couldn't run the code to see if it actually worked.

Comment: @JonasFollesø - Sorry, it appears that my answer didn't save. That sucks. I'll have to do it again.

Comment: Yeah, it felt like a smell to do queries inside the subscribe handler... Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: Awesome - based on your updated answer I was able to implement a service doing exactly as I want. A bit of a learning curve, but quite pleased with the result. I've created a gist with a working iOS implementation. Next I will do one for Android, and I might put together a small Open Source lib for Reactive Zeroconf: https://gist.github.com/follesoe/a79443207f4d7a3f06291cfc357bca64

Comment: It kind of work, I had to go with a `Merge()` over `Switch()` (to discover all services, of a given type not just one). However, now I'm struggling with "completing" the sequence. The OnComplete is never called in the example I submitted on the gist.

Comment: @JonasFollesø - yes, because the source comes from an event handler so is infinite. If you only ever expect one event from an event handler you should add `.Take(1)` after the `FromEventPattern` call.